# Calculate current time in percentage in relation to sunrise and sunset time?

Tags: javascript, api, momentjs

I think what I would like to achieve can best be described with the graph I've made below:

[image: Day Night Cycle In Percentage]

I'm getting my sunrise and sunset data from an API that returns an object like this:

```
{
  sunrise: "07:58:38",
  sunset: "15:52:46",
  day_length: "07:54:08",
}
```

I'm currently calculating whether it's currently day or night time with this if statement:

```
const date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")

let dayOrNight = "Day"

if (moment().isAfter(`${date} ${location.sunrise}`) && moment().isBefore(`${date} ${location.sunset}`)) {
  dayOrNight = "Day"
} else {
  dayOrNight = "Night"
}
```

All I need is a percentage value based on the current time in relation to this sunrise and sunset data.

For example, if this is my dataset:

```
{
  sunrise: "00:00:00",
  sunset: "10:00:00",
}
```

and my current time is perfectly between of both sunrise and sunset times which in this case would be `05:00:00` or `17:00:00`, then my current time would equate to 100%. `02:30:00`, `07:30:00` would equate to 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hi,

#### Solution

I think it would be logical to work with seconds.

- Find the day midpoint and night midpoint times. (day_midpoint_in_sec + 12 x 60 x 60 seconds will be night midpoint)
- Find percent_per_second for day and night (for day => `(day_midpoint_in_sec - sunrise_in_sec) / 100` )
- Find if given_time is day/night. (you have already solved it)
- if it's day time then set `elapsed_sec = given_time_in_sec - sunrise_in_sec`
- if given_time > day_midpoint, percentage is `200 - (elapsed_sec x  percent_per_second)`
- else percentage is `elapsed_sec x  percent_per_second`

Similarly you can easily work out for night time.

#### OR

On second thought,and on inspection of the graph,

- Find everything relative to sunrise. ( day_midpoint_in_sec , night_midpoint_in_sec and sunset)
- Apply equations depending upon where given_time_in_sec lies (good old `y = mx + c`) to get the percentages

We will get 4 equations:-

```
y = (100x)/day_midpoint_in_sec
y = (-100x/(sunset_in_sec - day_midpoint_in_sec)) + 100
y = 100x/(night_midpoint_in_sec - sunset)
y = (-100x/(24*60*60 - sunset_in_sec) - sunset_in_sec) + 100
```

#### Edit

Hi, as the second solution has become more complicated (also i have noticed some edge cases and mistake from my part), i have made a working snippet based on first solution.

```
let api = {
  sunrise: "00:00:00",
  sunset: "10:00:00",
};


const date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")

let sunrise = moment(`${date} ${api.sunrise}`);
let sunset = moment(`${date} ${api.sunset}`);
let hour_24 = moment(`${date} 24:00:00`);
let hour_0 = moment(`${date} 00:00:00`);

let sunset_till_hour24 = hour_24.clone().subtract(sunset);
let hour24_till_sunrise = sunrise.clone().subtract(hour_0);

let midnight = sunset.clone().add(sunset_till_hour24.clone().add(hour24_till_sunrise).valueOf()/2);
let midday = sunrise.clone().add(sunset.clone().subtract(sunrise).valueOf()/2);



let givenTime = "17:10:00";
let given_time = moment(`${date} ${givenTime}`);


function findTimePercent(time, sunrise, midday, sunset, midnight) {
  let day_percent_per_ms = 100/midday.clone().subtract(sunrise).valueOf();
  let night_percent_per_ms = 100/midnight.clone().subtract(sunset).valueOf();
 

  let percent = 0;

  if (time.isSame(sunrise) || time.isSame(sunset)) {
    return 0;
  } else if (time.isSame(midday) || time.isSame(midnight)) {
    return 100;
  }
  
  // isBetween is exclusive
  if (time.isBetween(sunrise, midday)) {
      percent = time.subtract(sunrise).valueOf() * day_percent_per_ms;
  } else if(time.isBetween(midday, sunset)) {
      percent = 100 - (time.subtract(midday).valueOf() * day_percent_per_ms);
  } else if(time.isBetween(sunset, midnight)) {
      percent = time.subtract(sunset).valueOf() * night_percent_per_ms;
  } else {
      percent = 100 - (time.subtract(midnight).valueOf() * night_percent_per_ms);
  }
  
  return percent;

}


console.log(findTimePercent(given_time, sunrise, midday, sunset, midnight));
```

I hope this is self explanatory.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on those last four equations? Obviously if I paste them into a JS document the syntax will be wrong. Please feel free to start a one to one room with me here and we can talk it through! https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/10835284/maximilian

Comment: let me know if you need any clarifications

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you!

Comment: How would we go adding a 2nd percentage value with 100% being midday and midnight and the start and end of each day and night being 0%?

Comment: I'm actually experiencing issues with this line `percent = 100 - (time.subtract(midnight).valueOf() * night_percent_per_ms)` after midnight last night the percentage was somewhere in the 300's

Comment: is there any way you can get the values of given time, midday, midnight, sunrise and sunset values for that instance

Comment: 2nd percentage value is very easy. just do 100 -  first percentage value. :)

Comment: I really cannot find why I'm getting numbers in the 300's or 400's with that logic. Please help. Given time: `2020-12-12T00:39:02+04:00`, midday: `2020-12-12T12:15:31+04:00`, midnight: `2020-12-13T00:15:31+04:00`, sunrise: `2020-12-12T06:56:15+04:00`, sunset: `2020-12-12T17:34:47+04:00`.